# SEF URL Issues on several sites

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, amp

I am running into an issue on several sites where the urls are "nesting"  other links in the main url structure.

**For example**: https://retrolube.com/blog/five-benefits-of-new-tires-for-your-vehicle/blog/five-signs-your-vehicle-needs-new-tires/contact/blog/five-signs-your-vehicle-needs-new-tires/contact/blog/five-signs-your-vehicle-needs-new-tires

We are running **K2**, **RS SEO**, and **JAmp**. I have K2 Set to "Enable advanced SEF for K2 URLs"

These are only showing up with an auto crawl from RS SEO. It is creating more than 1000 links! They are unpublished but added to the site map! Is there a way to fix or prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

The "enable advanced SEF" option in K2 is a standalone SEF router, and is most likely conflicting with anything that RS SEO is doing.

Without taking a look at your site, I can't really tell, but it is the most likely answer to your case.

Try disabling one of them (K2 advanced SEF or RS SEO) and see how it goes.